# Error in installing opencv 3.3.0 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, makefile, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install Opencv 3.3.0 in raspberry pi 3 and I'm following this instruction [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/)

But I faced error whenever I'm running -

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
 DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

[Here's my output of cmake command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzhjB.png)

Whenever I'm hitting **make** command It's showing me ***No makefile has been found.*** 
And If I copy a makefile from somewhere else to this directory It's showing me a new error like [this one!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yot0Q.png)

One thing need to be mentioned is I'm completely new to raspberry pi and tried every possible way to avoid this error but this error isn't avoiding me . Wishing great help from the Expert .

Comment: There's no point trying to run `make` until `cmake` completes correctly, but no-one can tell you why `cmake` didn't work till you show the actual error messages. Try removing everything in your `build` directory and running `cmake` again, and then show the first few errors, not the last. `rm -rf /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/build/*` then your `cmake` command again.

Comment: I followed that and result is stucked at 92%. It's showing me this one 
`Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:20875: recipe for target 'modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2

Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
`

Comment: Try replacing `~` with `$HOME` maybe.

Comment: I don't get it. Please elaborate . As I said I'm completely new to this.

Comment: ... where you soecify your EXTRAMODULESPATH use `=$HOME/opencv...`

Comment: It's very hard to debug stuff we can't see, or which is buried across a load of unformatted comments. Please click `edit` under  your question and make sure it shows EXACTLY what you ran and the corresponding error messages.

Comment: It's compiling again!! 
After using $HOME!!  Will inform you

Answer (score 0):

> 1st Solution

delete all the files from the build folder and run the cmake command again, cmake is loading the previously generated cmakeerror.log file.

> 2nd Solution

use the cmake GUI its more convenient, you can download it from 
[here](https://cmake.org/)

Comment: Still now after applying the 1st solution it's showing configuring incomplete, errors occured!! 

I have no idea about 2nd solution. Will you please elaborate it or provide me a demonstration link ?

Comment: try this 1- cmake..  2- make -j4 , i hope you are not editing the make file and also check the paths of the python 2 or 3 anyone you are using. another thing i just noticed that you are compling rasbery with opencv contrib 3.3.0 then why use opencv 3.1.0 in the path for extra modules. change it to 3.3.0, i hope it will solve your problem.